# Photo Competition: January 2019 - From the top!

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per month.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and the date the photo was taken
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content

---

Rules for January are as follows:

1. **It has to be a picture taken from the top/summit of something you reached, hill/mountain/climb/high point etc.**
2. The photo should not include people as an important part of the picture. If unavoidable, people can be included as long as they are not recognizable.
3. No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of January 2019, voting will be applicable till midnight 31st of January and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
4. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

Good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This photo was taken in August 2016 on the Fimmvörðuháls pass, between the Eyjafjallajökull and Mýrdalsjökull. This was an exposed plateau on the north side, giving a view to the east up the side of the Mýrdalsjökull, before crossing the snow fields to reach the south side of the glaciers.

[image: Fimmvörðuháls pass]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Reinefjord]

View from Helvete, next to the famous [Reinebringen](https://www.google.com/search?q=reinebringen&tbm=isch) on Moskenesøy, Lofoten, Norway. In the front is, about 700 meters below, the Reinefjord, the white dots just left of the center are the houses of Vindstad. The beach in the back is Buneset, probably one of the most beautiful beaches north of the polar circle. Picture taken in August 2015.

Comment: Beautiful picture, +1!

Answer (score 8):

[image: Looking towards Yosemite Valley from Clouds rest]

July of 2017 from on top of Cloud's Rest looking towards Yosemite Valley with Half Dome on the left and El Capitan in the far distance.

Answer (score 8):

Picture taken from the top of diamond head at diamond head state park taken on May 29, 2018 looking down on the crater of diamond head volcano.

[image: diamond head]

Answer (score 7):

[image: The view from top of Stok Kangri, 6153m]

The view from top of Stok Kangri, 6153m

Answer (score 5):

[image: Schrammsteine]

Schrammsteine, Sächsische Schweiz/Elbsandsteingebirge, Germany. Picture taken March 2014.

Answer (score 5):

Frozen summit of Garnedd Ugain on the Snowdon Massif

[image]

Comment: Please add the date taken (see the rules in the question).

Answer (score 5):

Hikers entering the San Juans from one of the southernmost summit (more of a plateau actually)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: From the top of Vulcan's Throne]

Taken november 23 2017, a few feet below the rim of [Vulcan's Throne](https://peakbagger.com/peak.aspx?pid=50783), a cinder cone that rises 800 feet above the [Esplanade Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esplanade_Sandstone), on the northern side of the Grand Canyon. Ascended from the river on a *rest day*, while rafting down the Colorado from Lee's Ferry to Pearce Ferry.

What's interesting is that even though it's a volcanic outcrop, the summit is actually lower than the canyon rim marking the horizon line.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Externsteine]

Looking from one of the tops of the [Externsteine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Externsteine) to the other. Picture taken in Teutoburger Wald, Germany in September 2018.

Answer (score 4):

This was clicked on 7th July 2017, at Mt. Kanamo (5974 m).

> *"Somewhere between the bottom of the climb and the summit is the answer to the mystery why we climb"* - **Greg Child**.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Looking north from Triple Divide]

Summer of 2014, looking north down the Clark Range from the top of Triple Divide Peak, Merced Peak is the one on the far left and Mt. Clark is the farthest right.

Answer (score 4):

[image: mountain tops in a bit of cloud]
This photo is taken near the top station of [the cable car that goes up from the Passa Pordoi,](https://www.google.com/maps/search/cable+car+south+tyrol+pordoi/@46.4985912,11.8065372,17z) in South Tyrol, Italy.
Photo by Willeke, (free for all to use) date photo taken, 17 September 2018.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Mitterkaser]
Taken on Sept. 03, 2018 at the top of a multi-pitch climb near Berchtesgaden. The rope on the right of the image is used by another party on an adjacent route with a slightly higher top. We had to rappel down since it started raining right as we reached the top, and descending via a small steep path seemed a bit too precarious...